# HTTPD - Forbidden

Tags: mac, httpd

Setting up Apache httpd (latest stable release) on a mac (Mavericks OS). Navigating to 127.0.0.1 when the server is up results in a 403 Forbidden. Any help is appreciated.

httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/paul/Sites/"
```

$APACHE_HOME/users/paul.conf

```
<Directory "/Users/Paul/Sites/">
Options Indexes Multiviews
AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Nothing apparent in error log

```
[Sat Sep 13 18:31:31 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Foo.local for ServerName
[Sat Sep 13 18:31:31 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Sep 13 18:31:31 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Sep 13 18:31:31 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) PHP/5.4.24 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.16.2 configured -- resuming normal operationFoo
```

Answer (score 0):

Posted this a bit too soon.

Solution:

1. I changed the Document Root in httpd.conf to som other dir - misunderstood some tutorial
2. as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750184/403-forbidden-error-when-accessing-localhost-on-mac-os-x10-8 I edited the vhosts file.